# login page in aurelia

Tags: javascript, aurelia

i am an aurelia beginner, i'm trying to prepare a simple app with login page.
But when i give validations, i am not able to setRoot for for login. because of the constructor is not allowing two arguments.con you please help me if there is any other way? find my code below for login.js.

```js
import {inject,Aurelia} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {Validation} from 'aurelia-validation';
import {ensure} from 'aurelia-validation';
@inject(Aurelia)
export class Login{
    static inject() { return [Validation]; }
    heading='Login to Aurelia'
    constructor(Aurelia,validation)
    {
        this.aurelia=Aurelia;
        this.email='raja';
        this.password='12345';
        this.validation = validation.on(this)
            .ensure('email')
                  .isNotEmpty()
                  .hasMinLength(3)
                  .hasMaxLength(10)
            .ensure('password')
                  .isNotEmpty()
                  .hasMinLength(3)
                  .hasMaxLength(10) ;
    }
    Submit()
    {
        this.validation.validate() 
     .then( () => {

         if(this.email=='raja'&&this.password=='12345')
        {
        this.aurelia.setRoot();
    }
else
{
            alert(`Invalid Credentials`);
} 
});
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't mix `@inject` with `static inject...`.

Change this:

```js
import {inject,Aurelia} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {Validation} from 'aurelia-validation';
import {ensure} from 'aurelia-validation';
@inject(Aurelia)
export class Login{
    static inject() { return [Validation]; }
    heading='Login to Aurelia'
    constructor(Aurelia,validation)
    {
      ...
    }
    ...
 }
```

To this:

```js
import {inject,Aurelia} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {Validation} from 'aurelia-validation';
import {ensure} from 'aurelia-validation';
@inject(Aurelia, Validation)
export class Login{
    heading='Login to Aurelia'
    constructor(aurelia, validation) {
      ...
    }
    ...
 }
```

Comment: tried that too but still not able to navigate. any way thanks for the reply

Comment: what module are you trying to navigate to?  If it's `app.js`, try `setRoot('app');`  Any errors in the console?